# The standard representation of symmetry group

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

The [standard representation](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation) of $S_n$ is usually realized by restriction to the subspace with zero sum of coordinates of the permutation representation of $n$ basis vectors. But I think the action of $S_n$ on vertices of a **Regular** $(n-1)$-simplex in $n-1$ dimensional space centered at the origin also gives the standard representation.( for example, $S_3$ acts on the triangle in $\mathbb R^2$) How to show this rigorously?

Comment: Thanks. I have edit the dimension.

Comment: If $S\in \mathbb R^{n-1}$ is a $(n-1)$ simplex, then we can identify $S_n$ as the group of isometries of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ preserving S, i.e. the symmetry of $S$. This gives a faithful representation of $S_ n$

Comment: By Preserve I mean send vertices to vertices. It seems that $S_n$ can be defined as symmetries of simplex. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903366/the-group-of-symmetries-of-the-d-dimensional-regular-simplex-is-isomorphic-to

Comment: Why don't you answer @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez 's comments? You must edit the question, and make clear that it is about regular simplices.

Comment: A catch is that a regular $(n-1)$-simplex is much easier to describe explicitly in the zero sum subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$! We can run in circles here  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are interested in the simplex representation of the Potts model in statistical physics.

The paper ["Functional RG approach to the Potts model"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03410) seems to have an explicit construction of the vectors from the origin to the vertices of the simplex.